# Create a select drop down of available menus

Tags: custom-field, menus

I'm attempting to create a custom field on my page creation that allows a user to choose which menu to display on the page. Right now I have my custom meta field setup, but can't figure out how to make a drop down menu of the available menus. Is there a function that I could use and then for loop though?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not intuitive but `get_terms` will do it, if I understand what you need.

```
var_dump(get_terms( 'nav_menu'));
```

If you look in the `*_term_taxonomy` table you can see why. The menus are stored as a taxonomy named `nav_menu`.

This won't get you things like page menus, only the intentionally created menus.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a code-based solution, the one from s_ha_dum is perfectly valid.

A out-of-the-box solution based on a plugin without any code editing would be [ACF](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) with [Nav Menu Field](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-nav-menu-field/) extension.